# How does lsyncd handle one of multiple destination servers being down?

Tags: server, synchronization, rsync, interruption

If we run lsyncd on a server and want to sync from that server to 2 or more servers, and one or more of those destination servers is down at that moment, how does lsyncd handle it? Is there some mechanism to automatically update the down servers as soon as they are back up?

Answer (score 0):

There is not a automatic process to handle your problem own by lsyncd.

When one of the hosts went down, lsyncd does not perform rsync (obvious).
When this host is UP again, lsyncd will synchronize diff between the last consistent state of the down server and when it come back up.
That's a normal situation.

Lsyncd is based on rsync, the process is the same.

But your question is maybe "When the server come back up, how lsyncd will detect him ?"

Lsyncd sychronizes on diff. If there is a file who changes on "master" server (where lsyncd is launch), he will synchronize on his targeted servers.
Whatever if server went down for hours for example...

I hope i answered to your question.

Kind regards,